# Catch-all URL with Flask when the path also contains a URL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, flask

Ok, so I want to catch all the URLs in my Flask app, with this piece of code

```
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return path
```

Just a basic app with shows the relative path of each page. So this works fine for most of the paths (`localhost/whatever/I/want` for example prints `whatever/I/want`).

EXCEPT in one case. For example if I type `localhost/foo/http://google.com/bar` in the URL bar, what I expected to be shown is `foo/http://google.com/bar`, but what I actually get is only `bar`. So actually Flask finds the last valid URL and takes the path following this URL.

Is there anyway to catch the real path of our URL?

**Edit:** I'm running Flask 0.10 using the [Google App Engine for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using Flask-0.10.1 as I got the expected output of `foo/http://google.com/bar` while accessing  `http://localhost:8000/foo/http://google.com/bar`.

Comment: Flask (and Werkzeug) do **not** behave in the way you describe. Are you certain you are not running any middleware or WSGI server that does this for you instead?

Comment: I bootstraped my project from the Google App Engine Python page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27, so I guess that there is the App Engine WSGI. Anybody knows how to fix that?

Comment: This is indeed something the Google SDK does, not Flask. I managed to reproduce with the current SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem with the current Google App Engine SDK; this is caused by the way the bundled CherryPy server parses the request.

The problem applies *only* to your local dev server, when you deploy the app to Google, a different handler parses the URI and the `http://` scheme is left unparsed.

See CherryPy [issue #1284](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1284/wsgiserver2py-breaks-on-uri-paths-which) as well as the corresponding [appengine devserver ticket](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/issues/detail?id=69&thanks=69&ts=1391650230).

The work-around is to URI-encode the colon:

```
http://localhost:8000/foo/http%3A//google.com/bar
```

works.